# Error when adding star on top of barplot in ggplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add a star on top of a barplot to account for statistical significance.

I'm using the script below. However, I keep having error messages although I used the same exact code from another post:

```
> gg <- ggplot(aes(x=category, y=mean, fill=split, group=split), data=data)
> gg <- gg + geom_bar(stat='identity', position = position_dodge(), width=.5)
> gg <- gg + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd, ymax=mean+sd), position = position_dodge(width=.5), width=.2)
> gg <- gg +  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Accuracy", "Precision", "Recall"))
> gg <- gg + xlab("Precision metrics") + ylab("Mean") + labs (fill="Classifier") + scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("k-NN", "Decision trees"))
> gg <- gg + theme(legend.position = "none") 
> 
> 
> label.df <- data.frame(Group = c("Accuracy"),
+                        Value = c(0.99))
> 
> gg + geom_text(data = label.df, label = "**")
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'category' not found
```

Here's the plot. I would like to add the star on top of the `Accuracy` red bar.
[image: the plot]

Any input is appreciated!

PS: I'm providing a `dput()` sample below:

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(mean = c(0.9685, 0.925333333333333, 0.985666666666667, 
0.926833333333333, 0.968666666666667, 0.931333333333333), sd = c(0.0150831031289984, 
0.0301838809079725, 0.013306639946533, 0.0589488478824367, 0.0147873820085459, 
0.0712338870669478), category = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), split = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("a", 
"c", "e", "g", "i", "k"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I think your variable names in `label.df` do not match the ones in `data`. You need the x and y variable names to match. Instead of `Group` it should be `category` and instead of `Value` it should be `mean`.

Comment: @qdread Thank you for your message. I'm still getting an Error: ```> label.df <- data.frame(category = c("Accuracy"),
+                        mean = c(0.99))
> gg + geom_text(data = label.df, label = "**")
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.
Error: All columns in a tibble must be 1d or 2d objects:
* Column `fill` is function
* Column `group` is function
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace```

Comment: Keep in mind that without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), we're just guessing what the issue with your data is. You say you used the exact same code as another post...did that other post have the exact same column names and data types as yours?

Comment: @camille I just posted a `dput()` sample of my data if that helps!

Comment: The arguments to `aes` in your initial `ggplot` call trickle down to the geoms you add on. The data you use in your last `geom_text` doesn't have the variable `category`, hence the error that `column` can't be found

Comment: @camille Thank you for your reply. I used `gg + geom_text(data = label.df, label = "**", category= c("Accuracy"))` for my las call instead, and got: ```Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: category
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.
Error: All columns in a tibble must be 1d or 2d objects:
* Column `fill` is function
* Column `group` is function```. I can't understand what is going on?

Comment: You can't just add column names in a geom, though. `ggplot` will be looking for columns with the name `category` in any data frame used here. You can set `inherit.aes` to false, or just add `category` to the `aes` of geoms that deal with that column

Answer (score 0):

You can try `annotate`. Furthermore it is recommended to use `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar`

```
 ggplot(df, aes(x=category, y=mean, fill=split)) +
   geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) + 
   geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd, ymax=mean+sd), position = position_dodge(width=.9), width = .2) +
   scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Accuracy", "Precision", "Recall")) +
   theme(legend.position = "none") +
   annotate("text", x = 1, y = 1, label = "**")
```

[image]